# Definition of Regular Point

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In "An Introduction to Manifolds (second edition)" by Louring W.Tu, regular point is defined as:

Deﬁnition 8.22. A point p in N is a critical point of F if the differential

$F_{∗,p}: T_pN →T_{F(p)}M$

fails to be surjective. It is a regular point of F if the differential $F_{∗,p}$ is surjective.

Under this definition, if $dim N=n, dim M = m$ and $n<m$, F does not have a regular points. So for a parameterized curve:

$F: ]a,b[ → R^2$

it does not have a regular point. Is my understanding correct?

There is other definitions of regular point of a curve, such as in "Elementary Geometry" by John Roe:

(7.1.8) Let $\gamma:[a,b]→R^2$ be a smooth map, we say that $t=t_0$ gives a regular point of $\gamma$ if $\gamma'(t_0)\neq0$, and a singular point otherwise.

Are the two definitions compatible with each other?

Comment: 1) Yes, that's correct. 2) Yes, they're the same. You should figure out why.

Comment: I think the two definitions are not the same. For example, a curve F: ]a,b[      -> R^2: x = x(t) and y = y(t) does not have any regular points according the the first definition, but according to the second definition, it may have regular point t0 if x'(t0) or y'(t0) are not zero.

Comment: No, of course they're not the same. I'm sorry for the dumb comment. The term for what John Roe is saying is "an immersion".

Comment: There are two different definitions in use - see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)#Critical_point_of_a_differentiable_map.

Comment: Thanks Mike and Anthony for the comments. I think the definition "Given a differentiable map f from Rm into Rn, the critical points of f are the points of Rm, where the rank of the Jacobian matrix of f is not maximal" (from wiki pointed out by Anthony) is better than asking rank(f) = m. And in the book "An introduction to Manifolds" it seems that the surjective property is not used in any proof.

Comment: It's NOT true to say "the surjective property is not used in any proof". Actually in the proof of Regular Level Set Theorem this property is used.